# How to customize visual studio code indexer files?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ide, intellisense, indexer

While searching for a better C editor I have stumbled on the following problem for visual studio code:

I work on relatively big C projects that contain a lot of duplicate files and there is a custom build system used from which I can generate if needed a list of all the files that I'm interested in indexing.

So, my question is the following:
Is it possible to configure visual studio code such that it will index only the files that I want ( currently when I try a "go to definition" I have to select between multiple files from which only one will be part of the build.

Also, is it possible to extend this to the whole visual studio code, not just the indexer ? Similar to a working set in eclipse, so when I do an CTRL+P I will only see the files that are part of the build.

I have tried configuring the include path in the c_cpp_properties.json but it does not seem to help.

Comment: simply, because they are duplicate files, just eliminate the duplicates from the build project

Comment: It is not just duplicate files, it is also different files that contain the same functions etc etc, and removing them will also affect the version control system, plus, I'm working on all those files based on the build target but when I'm looking through the code of one build target, I don't want to select each time for a function that is implemented in 4-5 files, the one that is actually part of the build for the build target for which I'm analyzing the code...